# Spring Security for rest api and website in single server

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, exception

I am trying to understand the best way to do spring security for the following case. I have a webservice, in which I have REST api + normal websites. All apis starts with /api/v1/... And all other format will be website format.

I wanted all the response from REST apis should be to be in JSON format. While the website will follow the html formats.

Ex:
if the user is not logged in nad hits thw following apis

> 1. /api/v1/system

shouls return

```
{
   status:401,
   message:"You are not authourized"
}
```

> 2. /index.html

should redirect the user to `/access-denied.html`

I am only using java configs, here is my security configs

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/protected**").denyAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(clientAuthenticationEntryPoint()).and()
            .addFilterBefore(new BouncerAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Can somebody show me how to takle this problem the best way or any examples.

Comment: If you just add a denied page, and set it in your web.xml, you can configure Spring-security to redirect to that page. And even if you are using rest, denied page also has error code. It is just a matter of your client reading the error-code. I still don't understand what is your problem.

Comment: I clearly mentioned that i need json response on api call and denied page on normal html page... And i don't have web. Xml... I'm using full java configuration.. Please read the post one more time

Comment: Okay sir, I know what you need via XML then, I had it as one of my bounty questions. Feel free to check it out....

Comment: Sure, i will go through it

Comment: did you find a solution?